# Select query on SQL where parameter1 OR parameter2

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, where-clause

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPPeople]
(
   @Name varchar(50) = null,
   @Status1 char(1) = '0',
   @Status2 char(1) = '0',
   @Status3 char(1) = '0'
)
as
   SELECT 
      People.Name, People.Age 
   FROM 
      People
   WHERE
      (People.Name = CASE WHEN @Name is null THEN People.Name ELSE @Name END) 
      AND
      ((People.Status1 = CASE WHEN @Status1 = '0' THEN People.Status1 ELSE @Status1 END) 
       OR
       (People.Status2 = CASE WHEN @Status2 = '0' THEN People.Status2 ELSE @Status2 END)
       OR
       (People.Status3 = CASE WHEN @Status3 = '0' THEN People.Status3 ELSE @Status3 END))
```

If parameters `@Status1` and `@Status2` are equal to `1`, the query should return registers that necessarily have `Status1` OR `Status2` equal to `1`, not depending on `Status3`.

But the query above returns all registers when I pass `@Status1` and `@Status2` as `1`.

Comment: Does this query execute?  It seems to be missing a Boolean condition before the last line (between Status2 and Status3)

Comment: It was really missing. I added 'OR' so it executes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this logic instead:

```
SELECT p.Name, p.Age 
FROM People p
WHERE (@Name is null OR p.Name = @Name) AND
      (@status1 <> '0' and p.Status1 = @status1 or
       @status2 <> '0' and p.Status2 = @status2 or
       @status3 <> '0' and p.Status3 = @status3
      );
```

Most people find it more difficult to understand `case` expressions in the `where` clause than boolean logic.

Comment: The only problem in this logic is that if I pass all status equals to '0' the query should select all registers, instead of none.

Comment: @EduardoMoreira, you could always just add `@Status1+@Status2+@Status3 = 0 OR ...` to your WHERE clause, and put everything else in another set of parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can modify your `WHERE` condition to compare against the parameter directly like

```
WHERE
People.Name = @Name 
AND 
(
People.Status1 = @Status1 
OR
People.Status2 = @Status2 
OR
People.Status3 = @Status3 
)
```